# ask step by step levenberg-marquardt in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to write `levenberg marquardt` in Java, here's my code:

```
    while (iter <= 10 || mse < 0.0001) {
        call.calc_jacobian(ff, trainlm, input, akt1, akt2, w, x, t);
        double[][] jacobian = trainlm.ret_jacob();
        double[][] error = trainlm.ret_err();
        mse = trainlm.ret_mse() / 4;
        mse_all[iter] = mse;
        test: for (int m = 0; m <= 5; m++) {
            upb.koreksi_w(miu, hidden, jacobian, error, w);
            double[][] w_new = upb.ret_upw();
            call.test_ff(ff, trainlm, input, akt1, akt2, w_new, x, t);
            double mse2 = trainlm.ret_mse() / 4;
            if (mse2 < mse || m == 5) {
                miu = miu / beta;
                w_skrg = w_baru;
                iter++;
                break test;
            } else {
                miu = miu * beta;
            }
        }
    }
```

The function `calc_jacobian` is a function I use to compute feed-forward and back-propagate operation to calculate the value of Jacobian. The function `koreksi_w` use to update new weight using Jacobian, error, miu, and actual weight, it will give a new weight and `test_ff` calculate feedforward to get `mse` value.

My problem is that when I try to run those code, the value of mse doesn't decrease, so I use `trainlm` function in `matlab` to run with the same input & weight, to prove that input & wight isn't the problem and in `matlab`, the `mse` decrease.

Comment: Does `mse = trainlm.ret_mse() / 4;` return something else but zero ?
If not, see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your piece of code, but are you sure it is `Integer division` that you want when you do :

```
mse = trainlm.ret_mse() / 4;  //OR:
double mse2 = trainlm.ret_mse() / 4;
```

As you expect a double, I would suggest a cast or something like so :

```
double mse2 = trainlm.ret_mse() / (double)4; //OR:
double mse2 = trainlm.ret_mse() / 4.0;
```

Check also `miu = miu / beta;` (is `beta` a double ?)

I suspect `MathLab` does floating point division where java doesn't...

Comment: yups, beta, and miu are double